# How can I flip an entire Tableview when a button is pressed in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, ios-animations

I have a tableView and a button in a View Controller. When the button is pressed, the data from cells is updated with other texts. I want to add a flip animation to the cells, so when the button is pressed, the cell flips and the data from cells is changed. My problem is that I don't know how to  add the flip cell animation.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to do this flip animation on cells?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  UIView.transition(with: /* your tableview */,
                          duration: 0.5,
                          options: .transitionFlipFromLeft,
                          animations: nil,
                          completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the working solution for me! Simple and easy and is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you one more time! Have a great day!